# (C++/WP8) What's the platform macro defined for WP8 platform?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

I already know I'm build for WinRT using __cplusplus_winrt macro, but I want to further distinguish between Windows RT and Windows Phone. Which macro should I check?

Comment: Now I know that even __cplusplus_winrt can't tell me I'm in RT platform, cause you can build RT DLLs that doesn't use /ZW switch. Someone help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the internet for quite a while I'm pretty sure that the only solution is to use project defined macros. It's not ideal, but gets the job done.

## UPDATE

Recently I found out these macros:

```
#if (WINAPI_FAMILY == WINAPI_FAMILY_PC_APP)
//You're in WinRT and it's Windows App
#elif (WINAPI_FAMILY == WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP)
//It's Windows Phone, but still don't know it's Silverlight Dll or WinRT Dll
#else
//Desktop
#endif
```

Now I only need to use project macro to distinguish between Windows Phone Silverlight and Windows Phone App, which I start to believe I don't need to ^_^